# Post Comment CakePHP 3

Tags: database, cakephp

I'm new on CakePHP and I need to develop a system where the user log in and post a comment, but I don't know how can I get his id and insert in user_id FK from 'comments'. Can someone help me?

**add function  - ComentarioController.php**:

```
 public function add()
    {
        $comentario = $this->Comentario->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $comentario = $this->Comentario->patchEntity($comentario, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Comentario->save($comentario)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Comentário enviado com sucesso'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Erro no envio do comentário'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('comentario'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['comentario']);
    }
```

**add.ctp**:

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Listar Comentarios'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="comentario form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($comentario) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Postar Comentario') ?></legend>
        <?php


            echo $this->Form->input('comentario');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Comentar')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is already logged in you can get his id with`$this->Auth->user()` or `AuthComponent::user()`
If you have no login System yet try the [CakeDC/Users plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/users), this should normally work out of the box and helped me a lot of times.